# Kinect Connection on Xubuntu virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kinect

I'm trying to connect Kinect Xbox 360, by using Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager/ Bitcraze VM 0.4.The virtual machine is using Xubuntu 13.10.

**My problem:**

I need to take the position data from depth sensor and use them in the trajectory control of a quadcopter. But i couldn't connect the sensor to Virtual Machine and couldn't find any accurate data about it.

If you have any answer or any source for the problem, can you share it with me?
Thanks,

Comment: Have you connected the kinect to an USB 3.0 ?

Comment: Yes, i connected it to an USB 3.0, but it still doesn't work.